# How can the value of a ansible playbook's variable is used in another paybook?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have two different playbooks named as **demo1.yml** and **demo2.yml** .

In **demo1.yml** there is a play, returned values of play is stored in register variable named as **results**. variable **results** has following:

```
"volume_details": {
    "status": "Ready",
    "Id": "123456",
    "name": "test_volume"
}
```

I want to use the value of `results.volume_details.Id` and `results.volume_details.name` in one of the plays of another playbook **demo2.yml**.

Is there any way to do use values of variables from previous playbook to another upcoming playbooks. I want to appreciate your efforts in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *main playbook* and import the others with [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html)

```
---
  - import_playbook: demo1.yml
  - import_playbook: demo2.yml
```

If you do so it should be possible to use registered vars from the first playbook in tasks within the second playbook. With `{{ results.volume_details }}`

EDIT:
To save a variable to a file you can use the copy module, with the parameter content=.

```
 - copy: 
     content="{{ variable }}" 
     dest=dest_file.yml
```

To load this file use the `include_var` module

```
- name: Include var of dest_file.yml into the new_var 
  include_vars:
    file: dest_file.yml
    name: new_var
```

Comment: Hi @yabberth, Thank you for solution, it will work when I have say 2 or 3 playbook in execution, but I have a sequence of playbooks and this main playbook will disturb the entire sequence. The `{{ results.volume_details }}` is required randomly in sequence like requires in playbook at 10th place, then playbook at 25th place in sequence file.
So, Do we have alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: Will the results variable altered after its creation? If not you could save the content to a temporary file and read it in the other playbooks whenever you want. [include_vars Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) may be interesting

Comment: No, variable is not going to alter, after creation to till deletion(which will happen at the end). Saving to temp file would be nice option and interesting.
If you have any example how can I do it like placing into temp file and then fetching in the upcoming playbooks,  because I am not that much aware about.and also tying to understand ansible doc for the same.